# Share properties of multiple objects to a single one

Tags: javascript

Trying to find the way how to share properties of multiple objects to a single object.

For example: I have the app object and the homepage object. The idea is very simple, I'd like to share the properties of the homepage object with the app object and be able to do something like this:

```js
const app = {...}

const homepage = {
  clickOnSignIn() {...}
}

app.clickOnSignIn()
```

- I know that I can simply merge this two objects, but this is not a solution for me. The plan is to add more pages in the future and still be able to use the dot notion on the app object.

**Update:**

I discovered another possible  solution for this problem, but I'm not sure if it's the correct way of doing things.

1. Created the Homepage object with some methods on this object inside `/pages/homepage.js` file.

```js
export const HomePage = {
  clickOnSignUpButton() {},
  clickOnSignInButton() {},
};
```

2. There's one more object and I called it the LoginPage.

```js
export const LoginPage = {
  fillUpSignInForm() {},
  clickForgotPassword() {},
};
```

3. I exported these files inside `/pages/index.js`

```
export * from "./home.js";
export * from "./login.js";
```

4. Then I simply imported these pages as a namespace inside my `app.js` file and created a few getter functions.

```
import * as pages from "./pages/index.js";

export class App {
  constructor(client) {
    if (!App.instance) {
      this.client = client;
      App.instance = this;
    }
    return App.instance;
  }

  static get pages() {
    return pages;
  }

  static getPage(pageName) {
    return pages[pageName];
  }
}
```

First of all, it works as excepted. Using this approach, I have access to all my pages thru my App class and now, I can do something like this:

```
const app = new App("some-client");
const { HomePage } = app.pages;
HomePage.clickOnSignUpButton();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*The plan is to add more pages in the future*"? Why does that prevent you from merging the objects (I assume you mean writing a single object literal)?

Comment: You're probably looking for `Object.assign(app, homepage);`. Or just `app.clickOnSignIn = function(){ … };`

Comment: Thanks Bergi for looking into this question. Not at all, it doesn't prevent me from merging the multiple objects, but I'm looking for some better approach of doing this. BTW I had a change to try your example and it didn't work for me. 

```
// app.js
export const App = {};

// pages/homepage.js
import { App } from "../app.mjs";

const HomePage = {
  click() {
    console.log("clicking");
  },
};
Object.assign(App, HomePage);

// test.js 
import { App } from "./app.mjs";

const app = App;
console.log(app.click());

```
>> TypeError: app.click is not a function

Comment: In that case you're never importing *pages/homepage.js* in your test, so it doesn't extend `App`.

Comment: Re your update: I see no reason to use that `App` class. Instead of importing the app module, instantiating the `new App`, and accessing properties on its `.pages` seems it could be simplified to just `import { Homepage } from "./pages/index.js";`. And using such `/pages/index.js` modules might have the downside that you always load all page modules regardless whether you need them, though this depends on your module loading setup.